# Problems opening javascript popup

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am generating an unordered list that includes hyperlinks from my code-behind. When I generate the code in the code-behind it looks fine, but it renders it weirdly on the page.

My code looks like this and gets the data from the database in order to populate the UL:

```
output.AppendFormat("<li class=\"depth-{0}\"><a href='#' OnClientClick='openNewWin('{1}')><span>{2}</span></a>",currentDepth,row["Href"], row["Name"]);
```

Heres an example of how the UL looks when generated in the code:

```
<ul><li class="depth-1"><a href='#' OnClientClick='openNewWin('AddressBook.aspx')><span>Address Book</span></a>}
```

In the HTML it comes out like this:

```
<a href="#" onClientClick="openNewWin(" addressbook.aspx')="">
```

This all calls a JS function like this:

```
function openNewWin(url) {

    var x = window.open(url, 'mynewwin', 'width=600,height=600,toolbar=1,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,left=0,top=0');

    x.focus();

}
```

The JS function works fine.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Use IE developer tools to make sure it is not perhaps the CSS applied to the page.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing single & double quotes in the code behind.  Make sure you're rendering valid javascript.

Comment: also by the looks of it, you're not closing the `<li>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generation line needs some fixing: you are mixing `'` and `"`, you have an unclosed quote, and you're leaving the `<li>` tag open.

Original:

```
output.AppendFormat("<li class=\"depth-{0}\"><a href='#' OnClientClick='openNewWin('{1}')><span>{2}</span></a>",currentDepth,row["Href"], row["Name"]);
```

Fixed:

```
//split to focus on the string
var frmt = "<li class=\"depth-{0}\"><a href=\"#\" OnClientClick=\"openNewWin('{1}')\"><span>{2}</span></a></li>";
output.AppendFormat(frmt, currentDepth, row["Href"], row["Name"]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks to have rendered better but when I click the link, it tries to use the # as the URL instead of opening a popup. The only reason I added the # is to try and force it to open using the popup but if I add the url to both the href="" and the function it just opens in a new browser tab.

Comment: It was the OnClientClick, needed to be onClick, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your html should render like this

```
<ul><li class="depth-1"><a href='#' onclick="openNewWin('AddressBook.aspx')"><span>Address Book</span></a></li></ul>
<a href="#" onclick="openNewWin('AddressBook.aspx)">test</a>
```

Use onclick instead of onclientclick.